# String to Clob in Java?

Tags: java

I have a string in java, but the datatype in database is Clob. How do i get a Clob from String?

Comment: Are you using an ORM like Hibernate or accessing it via JDBC or similar?

Comment: can any one guide me how to do same (get a Clob from String)  in hibernate ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`clob.setString(position, string)` [writes a String to a Clob object](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Clob.html).

Comment: also, many JDBC drivers handle conversion from String to Clob automatically, so sql.setString(1, string) maybe also just works.

Answer (score 3):

new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialClob(source.toCharArray())

Answer (score 0):

To Convert any String(small strings or big JSON converted to strings) in to CLOB we need to initialize CLOB first:

```
CLOB clob = (CLOB) con.createClob();
clob.setString(position, "Any String Here");
```

Where `con` is *Connection*