# convert string to oracle.sql.clob in java?

Tags: java, string, oracle, oracle11g, clob

I'm coding a Java function inside Oracle Database which produce allot of text!
how to convert a string to CLOB (oracle.sql.CLOB) in java?
what is the straight-forward way to do?

I'm trying to build a function which has **String** as an input with **oracle.sql.CLOB** as an output, but it's not working! I'm not doing any **jdbc** related work!

here is what I have (which is not working!)

```
  public static CLOB str2clob(String s)
  {
         oracle.sql.CLOB clob = null;

         try
         {
               clob.setString(0,s);

         } catch (Exception e)
         {
         }
         return clob;
  }
```

Comment: Check here please:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687696/string-to-clob-in-java

Comment: Or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454830/convert-java-string-to-clob).

Comment: Those two links don't directly provide what the poster is asking for...

Answer (score 2):

```
/*********************************************************************************************
 * From String to CLOB
 *  @return CLOB representation of string
 *********************************************************************************************/
private java.sql.Clob stringToClob(String source)
{
    try
    {
        return new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialClob(source.toCharArray());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.error("Could not convert string to a CLOB",e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: **This is possible but created Clob does not work properly!**

For example, invoking `yourClob.getAsciiStream()` throws SerialException: `Unsupported operation. SerialClob cannot return a the CLOB value as an ascii stream, unless instantiated with a fully implemented Clob object.` For more details please see SerialClob implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
oracle.sql.CLOB **clob** = ((OracleResultSet)rset).getCLOB(index);

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(**yourString**);
char[] bufr = new char[clob.getChunkSize()];


OutputStream os = new OutputStream(clob.getOutputStream());

int charsRead = 0;
for(charsRead = sr.read(bufr); charsRead>-1; charsRead = sr.read(bufr)){
   os.write(bufr, 0, charsRead);
}


os.flush();
os.close()
sr.close();
```

Comment: so my results are save as CLOB in **clob** ?

Comment: what about index in 'oracle.sql.CLOB clob = ((OracleResultSet)rset).getCLOB(**index**);'?

Comment: you write "yourString" (by using StreamReader sr) in outputStream of clob (clob.getOutputStream())

Comment: not working for me! I tried to build a function which has **String** as an input with **oracle.sql.CLOB** as an output, but it's not working! I'm not doing any **jdbc** related work!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NonContextualLobCreator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/NonContextualLobCreator.html) from Hibernate. Please see answers in [What is the alternate for deprecated Hibernate.createClob(Reader reader, int length)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304211/)