# What is the alternate for deprecated Hibernate.createClob(Reader reader, int length)

Tags: hibernate, deprecated, clob

Seems like `Hibernate.createClob(Reader reader, int length)` is deprecated in version 3.6.x
And it suggests to use Use `LobHelper.createClob(Reader, long)` instead.

But `LobHelper` is an interface not a class.

Is there any alternate for  `static method Hibernate.createClob(Reader reader, int length)`?

Answer (score 5):

I was using the createBlob(bytes[]) from that class. I created a new class and the following method

```
    public static Blob createBlob(byte[] bytes) {
       return NonContextualLobCreator.INSTANCE.wrap(NonContextualLobCreator.INSTANCE.createBlob(bytes));
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

It is the way of simplifying the usage by hiding the implementations. If you want to use the `Clob` data you need to use the below code. I have tested it in version `hibernate 3.6`.

```
session.getLobHelper().createClob("the_string");
```

Now coming your second point about the working of it, if you read the source code of `org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl` class you will know how internally hibernate handles this.

```
public LobHelper getLobHelper()
/*      */   {
/* 2245 */     if (this.lobHelper == null) {
/* 2246 */       this.lobHelper = new LobHelperImpl(this, null);
/*      */     }
/* 2248 */     return this.lobHelper;
/*      */   }
```

Comment: Thanks Manu for quick answer. But this required to get or open a new hibernate session. isn't there any static method like deprecated Hibernate.createClob(Reader reader, int length)?

Comment: Most of the time when you create a Blob or a Clob data type, you want it to be stored in to the DB. When you want to display it you have to convert it to byte[] or something like that. That's why it is been moved inside the Session I believe.

Answer (score 1):

I have found another good alternate for this,
using java javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialClob

For example

```
Clob clob = new SerialClob("Some very long String.......".toCharArray());
```

Comment: **This is possible but created Clob does not work properly!**

For example, invoking `yourClob.getAsciiStream()` throws SerialException: `Unsupported operation. SerialClob cannot return a the CLOB value as an ascii stream, unless instantiated with a fully implemented Clob object.` For more details please see SerialClob implementation.